# How to write text document in two colums in Lyx2.0.2?

Tags: lyx-layouts

How to write text document in two columns in Lyx2.0.2, as authors write in published papers?

Comment: `Document->Settings->Text Layout->Two-column document`, but you should look for a LyX template solution for whichever publisher you're writing for.  (Or just use LaTeX `;)` it's far easier to just write `[twocolumn]`.)

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to find a duplicate, so here's a proper answer :)

The menu item you're searching for is `Document > Settings > Text Layout > Two-column document`.  This is a fine solution for now, but I would recommend searching for (or asking for) some sort of LyX template for the publisher you're writing for.   LyX has some sort of analog for supporting LaTeX document classes, although I'm not sure how it works.  [The documentation][http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts] is your best bet if the publisher can't provide anything.

That said, it *really is* just easier to use LaTeX.  I don't want to discourage you from using LyX---it's a fine program that teaches good habits---but I still thank my professor for basically mocking my use of it.  (We have a very, uh, 'special' relationship.  He was also eventually my thesis mentor.)

In LaTeX, what you're asking for would be a simple change from

```
\documentclass{article}
```

to

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

Comment: BTW Sean , I just checked in lyx (2.0.2) , couldn't find  such option as Two-column document under Text Layout.

Comment: It's definitely there.  v2.0.7.1 2014-01-31 http://i.stack.imgur.com/EE8HR.png Sorry for the graininess; LyX (more accurately, Qt) doesn't support Retina displays yet.  Note additionally that a GUI element wouldn't change so drastically between minor revisions :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply. I already worked it out. For new lyx users , the following might be helpful if you want to write a two column document using lyx.

I downloaded IEEEtran to my Lyx/LaTeX setup.

1. Installing Lyx

   Can be done using the following set of commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lyx   /*If you already have lyx, skip this */
   sudo apt-get install lyx texlive
   ```
2. Ensure `texlive-publisher` is installed

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lyx texlive-publishers
   ```
3. Finally, reconfigure

   - Open Lyx
   - Click on Tools > Reconfigure
   - Exit Lyx

Then, select `article(IEEETRAN)` option from `Document > Settings > Document class > Document-class`.

That will do it.

Comment: Good information, but this doesn't really answer the question at hand, though. :) Also, you might want to take a look at the help center; StackExchange isn't really a forum.  I really would recommend you read up a little about it—it's a really good concept :)

Comment: How is this answer related to the question

Comment: Anywy was helpful